# How to countdown timer on hours and mins and stop when it's 0 , objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

```
  viewdidload

 {   
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    ctime=([df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"12:44"];`
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"20:50"];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
    int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
    NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", hours, minutes];
    currHour=hours;
    currMinute=minutes;
    currSeconds=00;
    [self start];
}

-(void)start
{
    self.timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired
{
    if((currHour>0 || currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0)
    {
        if(currSeconds==0)
        {

            currMinute-=1;
            currSeconds=59;
        }
        else if(currSeconds>0)
        {

            currSeconds-=1;
        }
        if(currMinute>-1)


enter code here
            [self.timeonelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d%@",currHour,@":",currMinute,@":"]];
        //[self.hourlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",currHour,@":"]];
          //  [self.timeonelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d%@",00,@":",currMinute,@":"]];
        [self.timetwolabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",currSeconds]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

On passing the current time and end time the timer should run to countdown to 0 .Problem is timer is not running to count down, Please help. I am even stuck in displaying the timer count down in tableview..please help

Comment: if((currHour>0 || currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0) executing ?

Comment: yes executing, currHour was not required have edited the code.

Comment: where you reducing the time?. after one cycle complete, nothing will happened right ?. @Shilpa M

Comment: Take a look at  `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, it's much more convenient for  displaying human readable time intervals.

Comment: consider currHour=1; currMinute=10; currSeconds=20; here how the values will change ?.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of thing wrong in your code regarding creation of date from a string. First of all, your specified date format in the `NSDateFormatter` and the actual format you use don't match - one has seconds and the other doesn't. This means that `dateFromString` will return nil. Also, you should also specify a date in stead of only time since you otherwise can't be sure that you will get today's date.

Finally, you are overcomplicating things by extracting and keeping track of all of components of `NSDate` in primitive variables. I would rather do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm"];
    self.endTime = [df dateFromString:@"2016/02/23 11:00"];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerFired {
    if ([[NSDate date] compare:self.endTime] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"still going");
        // enter code here
        // Use NSDateComponentsFormatter to show what you need to show
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"done");
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok..this looks good. Let me check.
How to make timer run in table view where end time is different for each cell?

Comment: I think the easiest way of doing that would be to subclass the `UITableViewCell` and move the `NSTimer` and it's functionality in there so that each cell has it's own. Of course, if you plan to do much more then simply displaying some values it might be an violation of the MVC pattern to have that much logic in the cell which is a view.

Comment: On second thought, doing it in the `UITableViewCell` might not be a good idea since cells get reused and maintaining the timers would become too complicated. Having an array of timers (one for each cell) in the `UITableViewController` is probably safer.

Comment: Hi, I tried with your code, but could not work around Using NSDateComponentsFormatter to show what  need to show and displaying it in the table view . Please can you help me with the code. endtime is in the format HH:mm:ss . I need to display time countdown HH:mm in one lable and ss in another. Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code  maybe this is your requirement 


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSCalendar *g = [[ NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];


    NSDateComponents *d_comp1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
     // lower value for  time  compare to  d_comp time
    [d_comp1 setHour: 1]; 
    [d_comp1 setMinute: 1]; 
    [d_comp1 setSecond: 00];


    NSDateComponents *d_comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    enter code here
    [d_comp setHour: 10];
    [d_comp setMinute: 1];
    [d_comp setSecond: 10];


    NSDate *date1 = [g dateFromComponents: d_comp1];

    NSDate *date2 = [g  dateFromComponents: d_comp];


            NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
        int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
        int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
        int sec = (int)d_comp1.second - (int)d_comp.second;
    if (sec<0) {
        sec+=60;

    }
        currHour=hours;
        currMinute=minutes;
        currSeconds= sec;
        [self start];
}

-(void)start
{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
 -(void)timerFired
{
        if(currHour>0 || currMinute>0 || currSeconds >0)
        {

            if (currSeconds < 0) {
                currSeconds = 60;
                currMinute -= 1;
            }
            if (currMinute < 0) {
                currHour -= 1;
                currMinute = 59;
                currSeconds =60;
            }
            [self.timeonelabel  setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",currHour,currMinute,currSeconds]];
            currSeconds--;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.timeonelabel  setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",currHour,currMinute,currSeconds]];

            [timer invalidate];
        }
}
```