# Countdown Timer of hour format in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I have set a timer in my view controller, it is working fine when i give any static number to it. Now i want to set a timer of one hour which decrement with one second and invalidate when reaches to zero. I have written some code ,

```
countInt=10;
self.lblTimer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",countInt];
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(startCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
-(void)startCounter{
countInt -=1;
self.lblTimer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",countInt];

if (countInt==0) {
    [timer invalidate];
}
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573340/how-to-countdown-timer-on-hours-and-mins-and-stop-when-its-0-objective-c?

Comment: what's the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: i want to set timer of one hour like this format HH:mm , it should decreament  with one second. @LalKrishna

Comment: @Nabeel Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766633/4061501

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLbl: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func pausePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func playPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if timer.isValid {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(reduceSeconds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timerLbl.text = "180"
        timerLbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

    func reduceSeconds() -> Void {
        timerLbl.text = String(Int(timerLbl.text!)! - 1)
    }
}
```

This will work as per 180 seconds and counter will reduce by 1 (as reqd) you can reset it or set it as to how so ever you may like.

**NOTE :**

`pausePressed` is a navBar icon and an action to it

`playPressed` is also a navBar icon and an action to it

Comment: sir i'm doing in objective c can u guide in objective c?  @Ashish Bahi

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
-(void) startCounter{
    if (countInt >= 0) {
        int minutes, seconds;
        int hours;

        countInt--;

        hours = countInt / 3600;
        minutes = (countInt % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (countInt %3600) % 60;
        NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

        self.lblTimer.text = time;
    }
    if (countInt <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"TIME OUT");
        if ([timer isValid]) {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is self.sceonfLeft? @Lal Krishna

Comment: `countInt` for you. I just created a property named `secondsLeft` to store time in seconds.

Comment: didChangeGameTimer method for? @Lal Krishna

Comment: it is hsowing error that delegate not found. @Lal Krishna

Comment: code updated. replace that delegate line with `self.lblTimer.text = text;`

Comment: It is just showing static format no timer is working. @Lal Krishna

Comment: i just used some other variable names. Now its changed to your's. Code updated. Please replace the method with the above code. You can learn basics [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_objective_c.htm)

Comment: Bro timer is not running its static 00:00:00. @Lal Krishna